# post css autoprefixer issue on parcel not showing prefixes

Tags: postcss, autoprefixer, parceljs

Autoprefixer not working on parcel 1.9.7: I have my src folder and I have .postcssrc file and styles file in the same folder content inside the .postcssrc file: `{ "plugins": { "autoprefixer": true } }`

parcel was installed with `npm install -g parcel-bundler`
pacckage json dev depenndacies:

```
"devDependencies": {
 "autoprefixer": "^9.1.3",
 "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
 "postcss-modules": "^1.3.2"
},
```

maybe anyone knows what could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe you didn't create the .browserslistrc file. Check out the [docs](https://parceljs.org/transforms.html)

Comment: Is this solved yet? I am kind of having same issue

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but can be helpful maybe for someone else. 
The only thing that works is putting

```
"postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
```

directly in package.json

So, package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "parcel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "prod": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "abstracts": "^0.2.3",
    "postcss-modules": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.23.3"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Massive big up! I wonder why this is still the case, and why the parcel docs are so out of sync with the reality of postcss as of the time of writing?

Answer (score 1):

Post-css comes with autoprefixer out of the box.

Parcel bundler comes with Post-css out of the box.

So the only package you need is `parcel-bundler` in your `package.json`. (Also you just need the "sass" package not "node-sass". The extra packages may be what's causing the problem.

To configure it all correctly try this sample postcss setup, where crucially the `autoprefixer` object and the `overrideBrowserslist` array are not empty:

```
{
  ...

  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "sass": "^1.25.0"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {
        "overrideBrowserslist": [
          ">1%",
          "last 4 versions",
          "Firefox ESR",
          "ie >= 9"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After adding a transition to an element in the CSS, the prefixes showed after inspecting and looking at the styles in dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Feb 2022 parcel 2.3.1 and autoprefixer 10.4.2

**I solved my problem by moving config into the `package.json` instead of `.postcssrc`** or other, btw the parcel docs does not say about this, **but the prefixes appeared only after inserting the configuration directly into `package.json`.**

**There is a possibility that for autoprefixer to work, the browserlist must be specified.**

```
package.json

    "postcss": {
        "plugins": {
          "autoprefixer": {
            "browsers": [
              ">1%",
              "last 4 versions",
              "Firefox ESR",
              "not ie < 9"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```